# Xamarin.Forms : "InitializeComponent" and "Package restore failed" Build Errors

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

After creating every single Cross Platform project in Visual Studio 2017 Preview 15.6.0 v1.1, I'm getting error from the picture, actually 2 errors.

> The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

The second error is related to NuGet Package Manager, I can't update any of     packages, error message:

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for
>   'testApplication.Android'.

[image: Errors from the description]

Comment: Check if your `MainPage.xaml` has build action set to `EmbededResource`
and `MainPage.xaml.cs` build action is set to `C# compiler`

Answer (score 2):

Failing some actual code error, i would try the following

In regards to

> The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

Steps that worked for me

1. Clean Solution
2. Delete bins and objs directions in all projects
3. Restart visual studio
4. Rebuild

---

In regards to

> Package restore failed

Try updating all packages for solution in the package package console

```
Update-Package  –reinstall
```

---

In regards to your comments when trying `Update-Package -reinstall`

> Update-Package : Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 26.1.0.1 is
>   not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1). Package
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 26.1.0.1 supports: monoandroid80
>   (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)

Also Check you are using the appropriate version of the Andriod Sdk

```
Tools > Andriod > Andriod Sdk Manager
```

Comment: I have tried to Update-Package  -reinstall, but I'm getting this error:"Update-Package : Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 26.1.0.1 is not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1). Package 
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 26.1.0.1 supports: monoandroid80 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)
At line:1 char:1" 

How can I change MonoAndroid Version, I have tried to change TargetFrameworkVersion, but after reloading my solution, it's again v7.1.

Comment: @AmerČehić You probably dont have the right  version of the Andriod sdk, updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to install new Android Sdk.

Answer (score 0):

One of two reason.

Your `x:Class` doesn't match up with the `MainPage.xaml` namespace. Male sure they match 
Or "Build Action" is not set to "Page" for `MainPage.xaml`